# Проблема с добавлением диска в apt

Tags: ubuntu

После выполнения sudo apt-cdrom add выскакивает ошибка:

```
W: Пропускается несуществующий файл /media/apt/dists/precise/main/binary-i386/Packages
W: Пропускается несуществующий файл /media/apt/dists/precise/main/debian-installer/binary-i386/Packages
W: Пропускается несуществующий файл /media/apt/dists/precise/restricted/binary-i386/Packages
W: Пропускается несуществующий файл /media/apt/dists/precise/restricted/debian-installer/binary-i386/Packages
```

Файлы на диске есть, только с расширением "gz". Может проблема в расширении, а может ещё в чем?

Comment: Вместо приписки `[решено]` надо принять один из ответов. В списке у вопросов с принятым ответом число ответов выделяется жёлтым.

Answer (score 1):

никакой проблемы нет. всё в порядке. это просто предупреждения.

вызваны они тем, что на диски для экономии места не копируют распакованные списки пакетов.

Answer (score -1):

Бинарные установочные пакеты должны иметь расширение .deb. Еслу у вас там .gz или .tar.gz - то это, скорее всего, текстовые пакеты исходников, предназначенные для компиляции. Похоже, что вы вместо диска с бинарниками подключили диск с исходниками.

Comment: Я не настолько глуп. Это установочный диск.

Comment: Если вы не настолько глупы, то попробуйте эти файлы самостоятельно распаковать и собрать! Там READ.ME есть.